# TypeError when I call a method from a class in Python

Tags: python, flask

I get this result when I call a method in a class without arguments:

> TypeError: unbound method getAge() must be called with Human instance
>   as first argument (got nothing instead)

I simplified my real question. I have three documents.

File: Class.py

```
class Human:
    age = ""
    def getAge(self):
        return self.age
```

File Get.py

```
from Class import *
    def getHuman():
        human = Human
        return human
```

File **init**.py

```
from Get import *
from Class import *
@app.route("/human")
def humanAge():
    human = getHuman()
    return human.getAge()
```

I create the class Human in the file Get.py and get the class from it. When I call the method getAge() it says that I have to use Human as first argument. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing parens in `Get.py` when you try to create an instance which you assign with `human = getHuman()` in init.py so `human.getAge()` gives you the error you see:

```
def getHuman():
     human = Human() # <-  need to add ()
    return human`
```